# I have a table in excel where I need cells to autopopulate based on some conditions:

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two series - say 11 and 22. Both of these have their own sequences, that is, 11 series has a sequence that goes from 1 to infinity and 22 also has a series that goes from 1 to infinity. But I only have one column where I am allowed to input the series.

I need a formula or any other way with which I can auto-populate this column in a way that the sequence takes the next number of wherever that series was last left off. To elaborate further, I have a table attached below:

In the table here, the last Sequence number for the 22 Series is 2. I want a formula to auto-Populate Line Items 10 and 12 with the next consecutive numbers, that is 3 and 4.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`=COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)` in `C2` and drag it down.

or

```
=MAP(B2:B12,LAMBDA(a,COUNTIF(B2:a,a)))
```

To spill result at once.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Okay that actually makes a lot of sense. Why didn't I think of that? I was running wild with ideas. Even thought of upgrading to Office 365 just to get access to maxifs. Thanks a lot!